# Error "CMOS checksum bad" after sudo apt upgrade

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, bios, grub, cmos

When I boot it up. It shows CMOS checksum bad error and goes to bios.
Then I have to exit from the Bois then it will boot as normal but with high brightness.
this all happens after an upgrade (`Sudo apt upgrade` ).
it shows that grub has been upgraded. why does it happen?

I tried upgrading again. and it install a new Linux header.
But still, it doesn't work.
I have win7 and ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
In win7 the time is wrong everytime I boot it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

- Installing Ubuntu 20, and if it still doesn't work, try install again Ubuntu 18.
- Try removing the cmos battery for about 3 minutes and replace it, and if it still doesn't work try buy a new one. If you decide to replace it, go to bios and set correctly the time and data correctly.

Comment: I tried changing the time on bios (coz the time is not correct)
But it doesn't work. I think I need to replace the battery.
Why does it happen after an update of the grub boot loader (version 2.02)?